# PHP Date and POSIX date

Tags: php, date, posix

I have two dates (from a datatime picker) that I send using post in PHP to this same page (I use a hidden `<input>` in a form).

```
$(function(){
    flatpickr('#calendar',{
        mode: "range",
        onChange: function(dates) {
            if(dates.length>1){
                $("#formdate .from").val(+dates[0]/1000);
                $("#formdate .to").val((+dates[1])/1000);
                $("#formdate").submit(); 
             }
        }
    });
});
```

Those dates are POSIX date, for example `1490569200` is `2017-03-27 00:00:00`.

You can see that I divide them by 1000; it's because I use them in MySQL so it needs to be in `second` and not in `millisecond`.

Here is my datetime picker :

[image]

When I valid this second date (here the 26th), it call the function above and refresh the page. If I do a echo of my POSIX date I got the following :

`1488326400, 1490486400` that are respectively the 1st and the 26th of March (normal behavior). Now I use the following function in PHP to convert them in a readable format :

```
echo date('l jS \of F Y',$from);
echo date('l jS \of F Y',$to);
```

It displays me the following :

```
Wednesday 1st of March 2017
Sunday 26th of March 2017
```

So until here, everything works fine !

But now if I pick up a date equal or above **the 27th of March**, here it's what's happen :

[image]

I do an echo of my POSIX dates :
`1490313600, 1490655600` that are respectively the 24th and 28th (so no problem).

But when I use PHP date for the readable format :

```
echo date('l jS \of F Y',$from);
echo date('l jS \of F Y',$to);

Friday 24th of March 2017
Monday 27th of March 2017
```

Indeed, every dates I pick equal or above the 27th will be displayed as the day before.

If I use `echo date('l jS \of F Y',1490655600)`, same issue, it will give me the 27th and no the 28th.

What's wrong ?

Comment: _"What's wrong ?"_ - someone has never heard of winter/summer time.

Comment: Oh dear... I spent hours on it trying to understand why it wasn't working and it was something that simple... Do you know how to deal with this in PHP ?

Comment: Sounds like your PHP code is not respecting the transition from winter time to summer time in that weekend for most countries (on Sunday the 26th 02:00 AM becomes 03:00 AM), whereas your Javascript code **is** taking it into account. If you add hours and minutes to your date format, does the date for March 27th 00:00 show March 26th 23:00? **edit** someone beat me to it :-)

Comment: I think I will set all my dates using YYYYMMDD format, it will fix my issue; thanks for replying guys ! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in the comment, that was due to the winter/summer time.